# r.water.outlet is returning blank raster in QGIS

Tags: qgis, watershed, qgis-grass-plugin

I am Getting error "￼Ignoring point outside computation region: 77.0072,12.2529" while deliniating watershed using r.water.outlet in QGIS. What am i doing wrong?
[image: Screen shot of output of r.water.outlet]

Comment: I think the description of your problem is too brief. What is your computational region? Did you look at the accumulation maps before setting the computational region? Did you provided the input drainage direction map usually generated from r.watershed to the r.water.outlet?

Comment: @Marco, my computational region is North:1570225.7,East:739499.1,South:1319713.3,west:474246 ,columns:8842,rows:8350. i have set E-W and N-S resolution as 30. I ran r.watershed with treshhold 55555 and got all 4 rasters.i have given drainage map as input to run r.water.outlet.

Comment: Then you have information in two different projections, I guess you are using the procession toolbox in QGIS and I am not familiar how QGIS handles the different projections withing a project to feed the GRASS commands, but certainly GRASS cannot handle them, it works only with one. how does it look a screen shot of the r.water.outlet? Add it to your question

Comment: I am using GRASS plugin and toolbox with QGIS 2.18.14

Comment: Hahahaha, I did not mean the text, I meant the accual screen shot from your screen when you open the window of the r.water.outlet command and have filled the available fields. When you edit your question, you can upload an image.

Comment: @Marco, hehe sorry, will do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `r.water.outlet` needs the outlet coordinates in the same CRS as the input file.

Since your "computational region is North:1570225.7, East:739499.1, South:1319713.3, west:474246" and in your screen shot says "EPSG: 32643 (OTF)" means your are mixing units. The outlet point should be meters as CRS and not in lon/lat.

My screen is a bit different from your despite I am also runing QGIS 2.18.14 and it allows me to pick up the point from the screen. Try to use the Processing Toolbox is on the right of my picture.

[image]